# Getting Intellisense / AutoCompletion for ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4 in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In Visual Studio 2015, how do I get intellisense / autocompletion for the ESRI ArcGIS API for JavaScript version 4.3. I haven't been able to find any documentation that explains how to add intellisense.